# Blueprint loop/for/while node with custom c++ blueprint function library in unreal engine 4 (ue4)

Tags: c++, loops, nodes, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I need to create a custom blueprint node. I am using the blueprint function library.

The node will look like this:

Input:
int timedelayforeachloop
int numberofloops

output:
exc loop
exc completed

loop1.h

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "loop1.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */

UENUM(BlueprintType)
enum class EMultiBranchEnum1 : uint8
{
    BranchA,
    BranchB
};


UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT2_API Uloop1 : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, meta = (DisplayName = "loop", CompactNodeTitle = "2as2", ExpandEnumAsExecs = "Branches"), Category = "1")
        //UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Meta = (DisplayName = "Multi Branch1", ExpandEnumAsExecs = "Branches"), Category = 1)
        static void multiBranch(EMultiBranchEnum1& Branches, int loopqty);
        //EMultiBranchEnum1::BranchB;

};
```

loop1.cpp

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "loop1.h"

void Uloop1::multiBranch(EMultiBranchEnum1& Branches, int loopqty)
{

    int currloop1 = 0;
    int temp = 2;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        currloop1 = currloop1 + 1;
        Branches = EMultiBranchEnum1::BranchA;


    }

    if (temp > currloop1) {

        Branches = EMultiBranchEnum1::BranchB;
    }

    if(temp == 0) {

        Branches = EMultiBranchEnum1::BranchB;

    }


}
```

-- THE PROBLEM --
The for loop only runs the once (evident by the print node i have on branchA(It only prints a single time))

-- What should happen with the code below --
the loop should run the 10 times (my print node should print 10 times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `UBlueprintFunctionLibrary`, you should use `UBlueprintAsyncActionBase`. It will allow you to store state in the node and call things connected to the execution pins asynchronously.

#### DelayLoop.h file:

```
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintAsyncActionBase.h"
#include "DelayLoop.generated.h"

DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE(FDelayOutputPin);

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class TEST_API UDelayLoop : public UBlueprintAsyncActionBase
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

public:
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintAssignable)
    FDelayOutputPin Loop;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintAssignable)
    FDelayOutputPin Complete;

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, 
            meta = (BlueprintInternalUseOnly = "true", WorldContext = "WorldContextObject"), 
            Category = "Flow Control")
    static UDelayLoop* DelayLoop(const UObject* WorldContextObject, 
            const float DelayInSeconds, const int Iterations);

    virtual void Activate() override;

private:
    const UObject* WorldContextObject;
    float MyDelay;
    int MyIterations;
    bool Active;

    UFUNCTION()
    void ExecuteLoop();

    UFUNCTION()
    void ExecuteComplete();
};
```

#### DelayLoop.cpp file:

```
#include "DelayLoop.h"
#include "Engine/World.h"
#include "TimerManager.h"

UDelayLoop::UDelayLoop(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer) : 
        Super(ObjectInitializer), WorldContextObject(nullptr), MyDelay(0.0f), 
        MyIterations(0), Active(false)
{
}

UDelayLoop* UDelayLoop::DelayLoop(const UObject* WorldContextObject, 
        const float DelayInSeconds, const int Iterations)
{
    UDelayLoop* Node = NewObject<UDelayLoop>();
    Node->WorldContextObject = WorldContextObject;
    Node->MyDelay = DelayInSeconds;
    Node->MyIterations = Iterations;
    return Node;
}


void UDelayLoop::Activate()
{
    if (nullptr == WorldContextObject)
    {
        FFrame::KismetExecutionMessage(TEXT("Invalid WorldContextObject."), 
                ELogVerbosity::Error);
        return;
    }
    if (Active)
    {
        FFrame::KismetExecutionMessage(TEXT("DelayLoop is already running."), 
                ELogVerbosity::Warning);
    }
    if (MyDelay <= 0.0f)
    {
        FFrame::KismetExecutionMessage(
                TEXT("DelayLoop delay can't be less or equal to 0."), 
                ELogVerbosity::Warning);
    }
    if (MyIterations <= 0)
    {
        FFrame::KismetExecutionMessage(
                TEXT("DelayLoop iterations can't be less or equal to 0."), 
                ELogVerbosity::Warning);
    }

    Active = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= MyIterations; i++)
    {
        FTimerHandle IterationTimer;
        WorldContextObject->GetWorld()->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(
                IterationTimer, this, &UDelayLoop::ExecuteLoop, MyDelay * i);
    }

    FTimerHandle CompleteTimer;
    WorldContextObject->GetWorld()->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(
            CompleteTimer, this, &UDelayLoop::ExecuteComplete, 
            MyDelay * (MyIterations+1));
            // If the Complete pin should happen at the same time as the last iteration
            // use `MyDelay * MyIterations` here instead

}

void UDelayLoop::ExecuteLoop()
{
    Loop.Broadcast();
}

void UDelayLoop::ExecuteComplete()
{
    Complete.Broadcast();
    Active = false;
}
```

This will get you a blueprint that looks like this:

[image: example use of blueprint]

Note: This code is heavily based on [This Creating Asynchronous Blueprint Nodes guide](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Creating_Asynchronous_Blueprint_Nodes) by Daniel ~b617 Janowski, now hosted in the legacy wiki [here](https://unrealcommunity.wiki/creating-asynchronous-blueprint-nodes-ctnmtj0q)